# Trying to install new features in Eclipse (using ADT as the base package)

Tags: eclipse, osgi, bundle, runtime-error, adt

When I try to install new features in Eclipse (using ADT as the base package) I get

```
‘Installing Software’ has encountered a problem.
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=profile, hase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).  No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.base,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.ddms,21.1.0.v201302060044-569685
```

I have installed a number of addons and I’m not sure which one might be giving the error.  If anyone else has faced this error and found a solution, that would be great.  Thanks.

Comment: what operating system /os version ? also the version of Eclipse you are using ?

Comment: Windows 7 home 64bit / 
Android Developer Tools - Build: v21.0.1-543035

Answer (score 47):

Try changing the address of the repo from http to https or vice versa

Comment: I was skeptical when i read this but it actually worked for me.

Comment: Indeed. The built-in repo url is starts with `http://dl-ssl.` and changing it to `https://dl-ssl.` fixed it. :)

Comment: As weird as it sounds, but this worked for me and should be accepted as the correct answer. Thanks! :))

Comment: Same problem, changed to https, STILL same problem.  On Android Source Plugin

Comment: This fixed my problem as well. But I had to do the opposite. I changed from https to http... Strange issue. Thanks!

Comment: @mwengler you need to change from http to https (or vice-versa) the android dev tools update site. Not the source code plugin URL. Actually worked from me changing to https

Comment: Anyone knows why changing the http to https fixes this issue?

Answer (score 34):

This worked for me:

> In Eclipse, try:
>
> Help > Install New Software
>
> Choose "Work with: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/"
>
> Select the updates to install and ***uncheck "Contact all update sites
>   during install to find required software"***

Answer (score 0):

I found similar information and how to go about fixing it on "Android - An Open Handset Alliance Project" here is the link http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=38267 I hope this helps you.

Another thing you can try is export your work space and re-install your eclipse. Sometimes the compatibility issue may cause this. I know this may require some work because then you have to add all of your plugins back but this might be the last option you may want to consider if you can't find a workaround or fix.

Answer (score 0):

The folder location it was installing the updates too, it didn't have full write permissions so I changed that and also changing the http to https. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Brilliant, I was on version 21.0.1 and my Tools were on 21.1 for some reason and changing from http to https, i.e. https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ seemed to work and ADT downloaded and updated.

On starting Eclipse there was no error message.

Sadly, on getting to the workspace what has happened is:

1. All my toolbar and menu shortcuts (except help/about) for ADT have been wiped
2. All my sites in the 'available' sites have been wiped
3. In general my Eclipse is now shagged

Well done Eclipse the plug-in nightmare system you've created has ruined yet another installation of mine. That's, like every instance I've ever had fails when I dare to install or use a plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it just by using 'http' instead of 'https' ( http://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ )